# What would be the meaning of the following expression?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

If I have a function r(s).

Then I could write down( in principle):

$\dfrac{d}{dr} (r'(s))$

But I have troubles understanding what this would mean and how to work with it.

Using leibniz notation I can write:
$\dfrac{d}{dr} \dfrac{dr}{ds}$

Which would lead me to think that I could rewrite it as

$\dfrac{d}{ds} \dfrac{dr}{dr}  = \dfrac{d 1}{ds} = 0$

But this seems like a total abuse of notation to me.

So my question is:
How to interpret and properly treat the expression $\dfrac{d}{dr} (r'(s))$

Comment: I do not think this experssion alone does make any sense, but perhaps it would help if you could provde some context.

Comment: Think first about what ${d\over dr}r(s)$ could mean.